# Multiplication in a quotient ring of the Gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

In order to prove that I={a+bi: a and b are even} is not a maximal ideal of Z[i], we need to prove that Z[i]/I is not a field. However, I am stuck at the step (1+i+I)*(1+i+I)=0 + I which indicates it has zero divisor. 
Can anyone help me understand how the above result has come about?

Comment: This is a question that ultimately tests whether or not you understand the underlying definitions. This question is really asking about whether or not you understand the definition of an ideal, and perhaps of cosets. I recommend that you backtrack a little bit and reread your book/notes on the definitions of rings and ideals (and perhaps of groups and cosets)

Answer (score 2):

Are you confused as to why $(1+i+I)^2=I$, or do you not understand why it's true while knowing that you need to prove it? The existence of a zero divisor shows that $Z[i]/I$ cannot be a field, since fields are integral domains, so the fact that you stated completes the proof.

If you're confused about why $(1+i+I)^2=0$, recall that for all $c, d \in Z[i]$, $(c+I) + (d+I) = (c+d) + I$ and $(c+I)(d+I)=(cd+I)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, actually I was confused regarding the step (1+i+I)^2= 0+I

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying my doubt. Actually I was confused regarding the step :- (1+i+I)^2 =0+I.